# Build from dockerfile exits, while from image stays up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been using this [Docker-Compose Repository](https://github.com/chriszarate/docker-compose-wordpress) for Wordpress plugin/theme development with phpunit and wp-cli.

Now I need to have soap in the Wordpress container so am trying to modify it to use my own Dockerfile.

When I build from an `image` reference in the `docker-compose` file, the Wordpress container stays up:

```
          Name                        Command              State     Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mz-docker-dev_mysql_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp
mz-docker-dev_wordpress_1   docker-entrypoint.sh apach ...   Up      80/tcp
```

But when I use my `Dockerfile`, it exits:

```
          Name                        Command              State     Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mz-docker-dev_mysql_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld    Up       3306/tcp
mz-docker-dev_wordpress_1   docker-php-entrypoint php -a   Exit 0
```

Here's a minimal version of the `docker-compose.yml` and my `Dockerfile`.

```
version: "3"

services:
  wordpress:
    build: .
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "${DOCKER_DEV_DOMAIN:-project.test}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "mysql"
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "wordpress"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ""
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "root"
    depends_on:
      - "mysql"
    networks:
      - "front"
      - "back"
    volumes:
      - "wp:/var/www/html:rw"
      - "./mz-plugin:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/mz-plugin:ro"
  mysql:
    image: "mariadb:10.2"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "wordpress"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    networks:
      - "back"
    volumes:
      - "./data:/var/lib/mysql"


networks:
  front: {}
  back: {}

volumes:
  wp: {}
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM "wordpress:${WP_VERSION:-latest}"

FROM php:7.3
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
      libxml2-dev \
      vim \
  && apt-get clean -y \
  && docker-php-ext-install soap  \
  && docker-php-ext-enable soap
```

And I run in detached mode: `docker-compose up -d`.

Am I missing a step when I build from the Dockerfile? Is there a configuration missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to have a detail look for [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

> With multi-stage builds, you use multiple FROM statements in your Dockerfile. Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each of them begins a new stage of the build. You can selectively copy artifacts from one stage to another, leaving behind everything you don’t want in the final image. To show how this works, let’s adapt the Dockerfile from the previous section to use multi-stage builds.

Above means, unless you explicitly copy things from previous stage to next stage, the items in previous stage won't be seen in next stage. For you, when you define the `FROM php:7.3`, this means your final image will be based on `php:7.3`, has non business with `wordpress`.

For next you got:

> mz-docker-dev_wordpress_1   docker-php-entrypoint php -a   Exit 0

This is because the `php:7.3`'s entrypoint is `"docker-php-entrypoint"`, the  container will exit directly after run the entrypoint if no foreground process there.

So, for you, just remove `FROM php:7.3`, base on `wordpress` image to do your customized works is the solution.